# In Azure, ML Pipelines, Error while training the model

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service

Please help me in training the model with large dataset or retrain the model continuously.

Also Do pipelines have any limitation on the dataset? if so, what is the limit

the error is as follows: "User program failed with ColumnUniqueValuesExceededError: Number of unique values in column: "message" is greater than allowed."

I want to train the model with binary logistic regression model,with a dataset of 3000 data points. while creating the pipeline , it fails at the training model step.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is 200 Throughput limits to Azure pipelines in general. refer below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops

Although your error does look like related to it but worth investigating.
Above link details some of the throughput parameters you may need to watch.